# Use php functions in Smarty template

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

How can i use array_push from PHP functions in Smarty Template.

I tried this

```
{assign var='out' value=array()}
{foreach $data['data'] as $dataInfo}
   {$out|@array_push {$dataInfo['a']}:{$dataInfo['b']}}

{/foreach}

{$out|var_dump}
```

Comment: Why? Surely you should be doing this in the model, or perhaps the controller, but not the view

Comment: I want the view decide how to display not the controller, but this is not my problem. I really want to know how to do this

Comment: Here you're not deciding how to display, but generate data - usually what the model layer is supposed to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't explained what result you want to achieve and in fact you should rather do such things in controller/model than in view.

However if in PHP you have:

```
$smarty->assign(
    'data',
    array(
        'data' => array(
            array('a' => 'one', 'b' => 'two'),
            array('a' => 'three', 'b' => 'four')
        )
    )
);
```

And in Smarty file you have:

```
{assign var='out' value=array()}
{foreach $data['data'] as $dataInfo}

    {append var='out' value=$dataInfo['a']}
    {append var='out' value=$dataInfo['b']}

{/foreach}

{$out|var_dump}
```

Output will be:

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" [3]=> string(4) "four" }
```

as expected.

`array_push` in this case is not the best solution because it will also display number of elements, so using:

```
{assign var='out' value=array()}
{foreach $data['data'] as $dataInfo}
    {$out|array_push:$dataInfo['a']}<br />
    {$out|array_push:$dataInfo['b']}<br />

{/foreach}

{$out|var_dump}
```

you would also get numbers displayed:

```
1
2
3
4
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" [3]=> string(4) "four" }
```

**EDITED ANSWER ACCORDING TO COMMENT**

> I want to display like this: a:b, c:d where this elements are| $array[0] = Array('aa' => 'a', 'bb' => 'b') $array[1] = Array('cc'=>'c', 'dd'=>'d');

If in PHP you have:

```
$array = array();
$array[0] = Array('aa' => 'a', 'bb' => 'b');
$array[1] = Array('cc'=>'c', 'dd'=>'d');

$smarty->assign(
    'data', $array
    );
```

In Smarty you should use:

```
{foreach $data as $dataInfo}
    {$dataInfo|implode:':'}{if not $dataInfo@last}, {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Output will be:

```
a:b, c:d
```

But it's not connected to the question in anyway where you asked about using PHP function `array_push` in Smarty template

Comment: I want to display like this: a:b, c:d where this elements are|
$array[0] = Array('aa' => 'a', 'bb' => 'b')
$array[1] = Array('cc'=>'c', 'dd'=>'d');

Comment: @OsomA What do you mean? You told that you want to put data into array. And `var_dump` function displays data only in its format. If you wanted simple display data why you wanted to use `array_push`? I don't get it. You should edit your question and explain what you want to achieve, put there original PHP data (in `var_export` and not `var_dump` format)